# AWS S3 Java SDK

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have requirement to upload streaming data from java program to AWS S3. Below is my program. I don't know part size while uploading the stream.

```
      if(!islastChunk)
            uploadRequest.withPartSize(5242880);
        else 
            uploadRequest.setLastPart(islastChunk);
```

So i have above logic to setPartSize as 5 MB when the lastPart is false and I set the setLastPart as true in UploadPartResult for last last part.

```
  package com.aws.s3;
  import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.nio.file.Files;
  import java.nio.file.Paths;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.stream.Stream;

  import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
  import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CompleteMultipartUploadRequest;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadResult;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PartETag;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.UploadPartRequest;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.UploadPartResult;

  public class MultipartFileUpload {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("ABC", "DEF");
    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    String existingBucketName  = "streamdatastore"; 
    String keyName             = "PeddlerGuideData.txt";
    List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
    //String filePath            = "";
    int[] idx = { 1 };
    InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse= initChunkDataUpload(s3,existingBucketName,keyName);


    try {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("MultiPartTestData.txt")));
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
        uploadChunkData(s3,initResponse,initResponse.getBucketName(),initResponse.getKey(),1,is,partETags,false);
        uploadChunkData(s3,initResponse,initResponse.getBucketName(),initResponse.getKey(),2,is,partETags,true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    completeUploadData(s3,initResponse,initResponse.getBucketName(),initResponse.getKey(),partETags);
}

private static void processLine(String line,AmazonS3 s3,InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse,int partNumber,List<PartETag> partETags){
    System.out.println("Line number "+ partNumber+"\n line = \n"+line);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(line.getBytes());
    uploadChunkData(s3,initResponse,initResponse.getBucketName(),initResponse.getKey(),partNumber,is,partETags,false);

}

private static void putMultiPartRequest(){

}

private static InitiateMultipartUploadResult initChunkDataUpload(AmazonS3 s3Client,String existingBucketName,String keyName){
    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new 
             InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(existingBucketName, keyName);
        InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = 
                               s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
        return initResponse;
}

private static List<PartETag>  uploadChunkData(AmazonS3 s3Client,InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse ,String existingBucketName,String keyName,int partNumber,InputStream inputStream,List<PartETag> partETags,boolean islastChunk){
    UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = null;
    try{
        uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                .withBucketName(existingBucketName).withKey(keyName)
                .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId()).withPartNumber(partNumber).withInputStream(inputStream);
        if(!islastChunk)
            uploadRequest.withPartSize(5242880);
        else 
            uploadRequest.setLastPart(islastChunk);
        UploadPartResult uploadPartResult =s3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest);

        partETags.add(uploadPartResult.getPartETag());
        System.out.println("chunk data upload is completed");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{

    }

    return partETags;
}

private static void completeUploadData (AmazonS3 s3Client,InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse ,String existingBucketName,String keyName,List<PartETag> partETags){
    try{
        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new 
                CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(
                           existingBucketName, 
                           keyName, 
                           initResponse.getUploadId(), 
                           partETags);

              s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
          }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }finally{

          }
      }
  }
```

When I set the part size as 5 MB, I always get the below exception.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: RequestTimeout; Request ID: 4B6405551FAABAFB), S3 Extended Request ID: v5RWy2tut1mEMzDZ1mwe0bFj6m9ho6eUihuO0p0EsccQtWv2814Ak18jtBNvxqDdt3AHy1otvTI=
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1530)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1168)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:949)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:662)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:636)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:619)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$300(AmazonHttpClient.java:587)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:574)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:446)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4035)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doUploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:3045)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadPart(AmazonS3Client.java:3030)
at com.aws.s3.MultipartFileUpload.uploadChunkData(MultipartFileUpload.java:81)
at com.aws.s3.MultipartFileUpload.main(MultipartFileUpload.java:44)
```

When I remove then logic that I have mentioned above, I am getting below error.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EntityTooSmall; Request ID: 11A9870A168EDBE0), S3 Extended Request ID: 7OnccoS26Ijd4SKvBj9mVvlH4SZk4oloNouNS5gc/QyS4DQXm5A24/Ds96WRHdlkr76nAaPSxR4=
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1530)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1168)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:949)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:662)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:636)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:619)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$300(AmazonHttpClient.java:587)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:574)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:446)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4035)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.completeMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:2806)
at com.aws.s3.MultipartFileUpload.completeUploadData(MultipartFileUpload.java:103)
at com.aws.s3.MultipartFileUpload.main(MultipartFileUpload.java:49)
```

Any suggestion on how to proceed with the same.

Answer (score 0):

Look at or consider using of [MultipartUploadOutputStream](https://github.com/libin/s3distcp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/external/elasticmapreduce/s3distcp/MultipartUploadOutputStream.java) implemented in s3distcp library.